# Pandas Left Outer Join with Multiple columns without same name and Rename

Tags: python

Could you please help me with this scenario.

I have 2 dataframes DF1 and DF2

[image]

[image]

I want to do a left outer join DF1 on DF2 and rename the column and final dataframe/result will look like this below

LEFT OUTER JOIN DF1 ON DF2
ON - DF1-VNAME = DF2-VNAME AND    DF1-OIL_DOI = DF2-DOI_NO ,  DF1-GAS_DOI = DF2-DOI_NO ,  DF1-NGL_DOI = DF2-DOI_NO  and rename the columns ALL_LEASES_OIL,ALL_LEASES_GAS,ALL_LEASES_NGL

*Final Table should look like below*

[image]

Comment: Did you try [`.merge(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`.rename(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) ?

Comment: My real data set have around 50 coulmns. What is mentioned above is an example Left merge and rename tried but not getting the results .

Comment: What did you try? Would you post your code here?